# jQuery Chosen - get (multiple) selected labels (not the value)

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

How to get the `selected` option's **text** from the **Chosen** `select`? 
So not just the `.val()` but the option `label/text`

Comment: You can simply use this to get the label.  $('.result-selected').html()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Used:
    `$("#list option[value='"+id+"']").text();`
To retrieve the `label` of the `selected` value

Comment: You should rephrase your question to specify multiple selects, and then accept this answer--works great; thanks!

Comment: What should the rephrased question best sound like? Because your answer does not result in an array right?

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use this to get the label.

```
$('.result-selected').html()
```

or

```
$('.options option:selected').html()
```

Comment: Hi, I use Multiple Select. What I really want is to get an array of the text and values of the selected options (multiple)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#objId option :selected").text();
```

Above **jQuery** statement should do it for.

Comment: This should give you fair idea about how to use...
http://jsfiddle.net/aaadesh/LCdXe/3/

Answer (score 3):

//Below code return name of the drop downn

```
$('#availableRevisionBatch option:selected').text()
```

//Below code return value of the drop downn

```
$('#availableRevisionBatch option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way that work for me, was doing something like this:

```
var options = $("#ddl option:selected");

var values = $.map(options, function (option) {
    return option.text;
});
```

Where values is an array.

Hope that it helps...

Answer (score 2):

You can check this for single select.

```
<select class="chzn-select" id="CHSNID" onchange="alert($('#CHSNID_chzn a span').text())">
```

Or

```
$(function(){
     $('#CHSNID').change(function(){
     var text = $('#CHSNID_chzn a span').text();
     console.log(text);
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get text values for multiple select:

```
<select id="sTags" class="chosen" multiple />
```

Jquery:

```
    $.map($("#sTags_chosen").find(".search-choice span"), function (option) {
        return $(option).text()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the above answers worked for me and so after searching a lot finally got the answer to retrieve the "label" value of the selected element

```
$("#your_select_id option:selected").attr('label');
```

Comment: Could be very well true because of a newer version of Chosen?

Comment: `$("#denominator-bnf option:selected").text();` worked for me with the latest version of Chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The below will get the label & here is a JSFiddle showing how to get the chosen dropdown's value or label field using the latest chosen jquery plug-in version 1.4.2. https://jsfiddle.net/hayoeu/4usazfdm/2/

```
$(".chzn-select option:selected").text();
```